# How to play video on a sony smartwatch?

Tags: video, sony, sony-smartwatch

I have been trying to play video on my sony smartwatch2.
But there is no API like sendVideo() or something.

Could someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right, there is no API to send video. It can be simulated by sending images  - showBitmap

Comment: To add to this the limiting factor in video playback on the SW2 is the bandwidth supported by Bluetooth.  While it can be done by sending bitmaps to the watch the playback will be quite slow.